# outer apply in laravel model call

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

use php laravel select data, how to add outer apply to laravel code?

```
    $data_result = tableA_model::where(function($query) use ($input) {
      $query->where('city', '=',  $input['city'] );
    }
```

i need sql like:

```
select *, (select top 1 name from imglist where id=tableA.id order by cover desc) as picname FROM tableA where ...
```

or

```
select * from tableA outer apply (select top 1 name as picname from imglist where id=tableA.id order by cover desc) img where ....
```

how can i get such a outer apply in laravel ?

Comment: You can use a [raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions).

Comment: Not an answer but you can probably achieve the same result using a `LEFT JOIN` which you can actually code using `leftJoin(...)` of the query builder

Comment: or how can take tableA item and get item first photo (in table:imglist) use one sql get in laravel?

Comment: i use ''->select(DB::raw("*,(select top 1 name from imglist where imglist.housen=tableA.housen and types='ding' order by cover desc) as picname"));'' solve this, thanks