# How can I use OUTER APPLY in Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'd like to use SQL Server's `OUTER APPLY` in Laravel for a query like this:

```
SELECT ACol1, ACol2, b.BCol2
FROM tblA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 BCol2 
             FROM tblB WHERE BCol1 = tblA.ACol1
             ORDER BY ins_dtim DESC) b
```

However, [as](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-with-outer-apply-from-sqlserver) [infered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427665/outer-apply-in-laravel-model-call), Laravel doesn't offer any direct method for `OUTER APPLY`. I was thinking of using raw expressions to cope with this, but the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#raw-expressions) only describes raw methods for `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `ORDER`, etc. Is there a workaround to archive this, or a library capable of using `OUTER APPLY`. I'd like to avoid, if possible, nested subqueries, views or stored procedures.
Thanks!

Comment: In that case you can use your complete select raw query in `select` method like this `$result = DB::connection('<connection_name>')->select($query, $bindings);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A raw expression can be utilized to accomplish the desired outcome. However, this method uses a subquery. Try the following.

```
DB::table('tblA')
    ->select('ACol1', 'ACol2', 'b.BCol2')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT TOP 1 BCol2 FROM tblB WHERE BCol1 = tblA.ACol1 ORDER BY ins_dtim DESC) AS b'))
    ->get();
```